# How to find One hour before and One hour after from reminder Time

Tags: javascript

I need to display the time one hour before and one hour after my reminder time. Suppose my reminder time is 11 Am the reminder need to show from 10 am and ends at 12 pm. now it's showing the whole day.
reminder_date is my reminder time

```
var countDownDate = new Date($('#end_time').val()).getTime();
 var countStartDate = new Date($('#start_time').val()).getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();
var dsr = <?=$todo['dsr']?>;
if(dsr.length> 0){
let dsr_str ='<ul>';
$.each(dsr, function(index, item){
 let now = new moment(item['reminder_date']);
 var start_distance = countStartDate - now;
if(start_distance < 0){
var distance = countDownDate - now;
 dsr_str += '<li>'+item['company']+' | '+item['phone']+' | <b>'+now.format("hh:mm A")+'</b></li>';});
 dsr_str +='</ul>'
 $(document).Toasts('create', {
 title: 'DSR Reminder',
 class: 'bg-success', 
  body: dsr_str
  })
  }
 if (distance < 0) {
 clearInterval(x);
 location.reload(true);
  }
}
}, 1000); 
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add/substract 3600000 (60 min * 60sec * 1000 ms) from countDownDate /countStartDate which are just numbers of milliseconds

```
var countDownDate = new Date($('#end_time').val()).getTime();
var countStartDate = new Date($('#start_time').val()).getTime();
countDownDate+=3600000;
countStartDate-=3600000;
```

Or use
start_distance < 3600000

which will check if current time is less than an hour before the start date

Comment: actually, I don't know how to put in my code can you help me Dobromir Velev

Comment: only this much need to add in code Dobromir Velev

Comment: Lines 3-4 in the code above will add an hour to countDownDate and substract an hour from countStartDate. The first 2 lines are just to help you see where to put it

Comment: sorry i didnt under stand can you put in my code  Dobromir Velev

Comment: No, I cannot put it in your code - you just need to copy the lines with 3600000  in them and paste them

Comment: only need to add this much  Dobromir Velev